# Java - number in expanded form

Tags: java, algorithm

I have given number and want it to return as a String in expanded form. For example

```
expandedForm(12); # Should return "10 + 2"
expandedForm(42); # Should return "40 + 2"
expandedForm(70304); # Should return "70000 + 300 + 4"
```

My function works for first and second case, but with 70304 it gives this:

```
70 + 00 + 300 + 000 + 4
```

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public static String expandedForm(int num)
{

  String[] str = Integer.toString(num).split("");
  String result = "";

  for(int i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
    if(Integer.valueOf(str[i]) > 0) {
      for(int j = i; j < str.length-1; j++) {
        str[j] += '0';
      }
    }
  }

  result = Arrays.toString(str);
  result = result.substring(1, result.length()-1).replace(",", " +");
  System.out.println(result);

  return result;
}
```

I think there's a problem with the second loop, but can't figure out why.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be adding '0's to `str[i]`, not `str[j]`:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
    if(Integer.valueOf(str[i]) > 0) {
      for(int j = i; j < str.length-1; j++) {
        str[i] += '0';
      }
    }
  }
```

This will result in:

```
70000 + 0 + 300 + 0 + 4
```

You still have to get rid of the 0 digits.

One possible way to get rid of them:

```
result = result.substring(1, result.length()-1).replace(", 0","").replace(",", " +");
```

Now the output is

```
70000 + 300 + 4
```

Comment: ``result.replace(" + 0","")`` would be easier?

Answer (score 6):

Pseudocode uses integer arithmetics to extract decimal digits one-by-one (from the right one):

```
mul = 1    //will contain power of 10
while (num > 0):
     dig = num % 10    //integer modulo retrieves the last digit
     if (dig > 0):   //filter out zero summands
          add (dig * mul) to output   //like 3 * 100 = 300
     num = num / 10 //integer division removes the last decimal digit  6519 => 651
     mul = mul * 10    //updates power of 10 for the next digit
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do the same with pure math, using modulo `%` and integer division `/`, e.g. using `Stream` API:

```
int n = 70304;
String res = IntStream
        .iterate(1, k -> n / k > 0, k -> k * 10) // divisors
        .map(k -> (n % (k*10) / k ) * k)         // get 1s, 10s, 100s, etc.
        .filter(x -> x > 0)                      // throw out zeros
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)             // convert to string
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" + "));     // join with '+'
System.out.println(res); // 4 + 300 + 70000
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If because the terms are in reverse order, well, _if_ that is important, the order could easily be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There are many variations possible. If the usage of a list is allowed:

```
public static String expandedForm(int num){

    String[] str = Integer.toString(num).split("");
    String result;
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(Integer.valueOf(str[i]) > 0){
            String s = str[i];
            for(int j = i; j < str.length - 1; j++){
                s += '0';
            }
            l.add(s);
        }
    }

    result = l.toString();
    result = result.substring(1, result.length() - 1).replace(",", " +");
    System.out.println(result);

    return result;
}
```

One could also work directly on result:

```
public static String expandedForm2(int num){

    String[] str = Integer.toString(num).split("");
    String result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(Integer.valueOf(str[i]) > 0){
            result += str[i];
            for(int j = i; j < str.length - 1; j++){
                result += '0';
            }
            result += " + ";
        }
    }
    result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 3);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible to do recursively. Here an example implementation:

```
String g(int n, int depth){     // Recursive method with 2 int parameters & String return-type
  int remainder = n % depth;    //  The current recursive remainder
  if(depth < n){                //  If we aren't done with the number yet:
    int nextDepth = depth * 10; //   Go to the next depth (of the power of 10)
    int nextN = n - remainder;  //   Remove the remainder from the input `n`
                                //   Do a recursive call with these next `n` and `depth`
    String resultRecursiveCall = g(nextN, nextDepth);
    if(remainder != 0){         //   If the remainder was not 0:
                                //    Append a " + " and this remainder to the result
      resultRecursiveCall += " + " + remainder;
    }
    return resultRecursiveCall; //   And return the result
  } else{                       //  Else:
    return Integer.toString(n); //   Simply return input `n` as result
  }
}

String f(int n){                // Second method so we can accept just integer `n`
  return g(n, 1);               //  Which will call the recursive call with parameters `n` and 1
}
```

The second method is so we can call the method with just a single input `n`. For example:

```
String result = f(70304);
```

Which will result in the String `70000 + 300 + 4`.

[**Try it online.**](https://ideone.com/mxjwAp)

---

To explain a bit more in depth of what this recursive method does, let's just do a step-by-step for the input `70304`:

1. In the first recursive iteration: `n=70304`, `depth=1`, `remainder=70304%1 = 0`.

   - Since `depth < n` is truthy, it will do a recursive call with `70304-0` and `1*10`
   - And since `remainder` is 0, it will append nothing more to the result
2. In the second recursive iteration: `n=70304`, `depth=10`, `remainder=70304%10 = 4`.

   - Since `depth < n` is still truthy, it will do a recursive call with `70304-4` and `10*10`
   - And since `remainder` is 4, it will append a `" + "` and this `4` to the result
3. In the third recursive iteration: `n=70300`, `depth=100`, `remainder=70300%100 = 0`.

   - Since `depth < n` is still truthy, it will do a recursive call with `70300-0` and `100*10`
   - And since `remainder` is 0, it will append nothing more to the result
4. In the fourth recursive iteration: `n=70300`, `depth=1000`, `remainder=70300%1000 = 300`.

   - Since `depth < n` is still truthy, it will do a recursive call with `70300-300` and `1000*10`
   - And since `remainder` is 300, it will append a `" + "` and this `300` to the result
5. In the fifth recursive iteration: `n=70000`, `depth=10000`, `remainder=70000%10000 = 0`.

   - Since `depth < n` is still truthy, it will do a recursive call with `70000-0` and `10000*10`
   - And since `remainder` is 0, it will append nothing more to the result
6. In the sixth recursive iteration: `n=70000`, `depth=100000`, `remainder=70000%100000 = 70000`.

   - Since now `depth < n` is falsey, it won't do any more recursive calls, but instead return the current `n` (which is `70000`).

And since these were all recursive calls, we should actually look at it backwards for the result, so it will result in `70000 + 300 + 4`.

So in general:

- The `depth < n` if-check is to see when we are done with the recursive calls.
- The `g(n-remainder, depth*10)` will remove the digits we've already output in a previous recursive iteration, and goes to the next 10<sup>`k`</sup> power in the next recursive iteration
- The `remainder != 0` if-check determines if the number we want to append was not a `0`

Comment: Nice, you posted it here as well, I just noticed, more than two years later 

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Kata
{

    public static String expandedForm(int num)
    {
        String outs = "";
        for (int i = 10; i < num; i *= 10) {
            int rem = num % i;
            outs = (rem > 0) ? " + " + rem + outs : outs;
            num -= rem;
        }
        outs = num + outs;

        return outs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package backup;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class FileOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String expForm = expandedForm(70304);
        //System.out.println(expForm);

    }

    public static String expandedForm(int num)
    {

      String[] str = Integer.toString(num).split("");
      String result = "";

      for(int i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
        if(Integer.valueOf(str[i]) > 0) {
          for(int j = i; j < str.length-1; j++) {
            str[i] += '0';
          }
        }
      }

      result = Arrays.toString(str);
      result = result.substring(1, result.length()-1).replace(",", " +");
      System.out.println(result);

      return result;
    }
}
```

**Output** : 70000 + 0 + 300 + 0 + 4

Solution in most inner loop you need to add '0'  to `str[i]` : `str[i] += '0';`

Then you need to replace "+ 0" from the resulted output.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(Integer.valueOf(str[i]) > 0) {
        for(int j = 0; j < str.length - i - 1; j++) {
            str[i] += '0';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add explanations to your answers, not only paste code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the challenge of this problem is omitting 0(zero) and extra +(plus) while iterating throughout the number. String concat function can be used with condition as bellow:

```
  public static String expandedForm(int num) {
    String st = String.valueOf(num);
    String finalResult = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
         String s = String.valueOf(st.charAt(i));
        if (Integer.valueOf(s) > 0) {
            for (int j = i; j < st.length() - 1; j++) {
                s = s.concat("0");
            }

            if (i == st.length() - 1) {
                finalResult = finalResult.concat(s);
            } else {
                finalResult = finalResult.concat(s + " + ");
            }       
        }
    }
    return finalResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String expandedForm(int num)
{

  String[] str = Integer.toString(num).split("");
  String result = "";
  String st="";
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
    if(Integer.valueOf(str[i]) > 0) {
      for(int j = i; j < str.length-1; j++) {
        str[i] += '0';
      }
    }
  }

  for(String s:str) {
  st += s+" ";
  }
  result=st;
  result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1).replace(" 0","").replace(" ", " + ");
  System.out.println(result);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Consider providing a bit of context with the code snippet, perhaps mention where was the problem, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String expandedForm(int num)
{
    int numberOfDigits =(int) Math.floor(Math.log10(num)+1);
    String result="";
    while(numberOfDigits-->0){
        int divisor = (int)Math.pow(10,numberOfDigits);
        int quotient = num/divisor;
        num%=divisor;
        int value = quotient * divisor;
        if(value!=0)
            result+=value+(numberOfDigits != 0 ?"+":"");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Try with this.

Find number of digits and iterate for every single digit.

Make a divisor of 10 power (number of digits -1) and divide the number to get quotient.

Take reminder for next iteration.

Multiply quotient and divisor and store in result if it value is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Javascript Expanded Form of a number
Asked in interviews for beginners/Juniors

```
function expandedForm(n){
let temp = n;
let count=0;
while(temp>0){
    console.log(((temp%10)*(10**count)));
    count++;
    temp = Math.floor(temp/10); 
}
```

}

output will be like this:-

> 7
> 80
> 400
> 5000
> 10000